# Not fetch a LAZY relation if I call from a method which calls after another Transactional method

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions

In my Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE application I have a problem when I try to fetch a LAZY field.

The problem occurs in a service method, `createWayBillFromInvoice`, which marked as `@Transactional`.

**Case A:** I call this method from a controller directly it executes with no problem.

**Case B:** I call the same method from another service method which is not itself Transactional 
my LAZY fields not fetch.

So I assume it is about Transaction management but I could not find the reason.

The method where my LAZY fields not fetched (and fetched in a direct-call):

```
@Transactional
public createWayBillFromInvoice(){
    Invoice invoice = invoiceRepository.getInvoice(invoiceId);//invoice is selected
    Order order = invoice.getOrder();
}
```

Here my `order` relation is not null but not initialized and not proxied, so If I call `order.getOtherRelations` it returns empty.

In case B I call something like:

```
public void create(){ //This method IS NOT Transactional
   invoiceService.createInvoice();//This method is Transactional
   waybillService.createWaybilFromInvoice();//The method declared above
}
```

I tried:

- Make the `create` method `Transactional`
- Set propagation to `REQUIRES_NEW` for `createWaybillFromInvoice`

Here are some logs:

```
2020-06-04 17:17:16.337 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [io.salesart.billingservice.service.impl.WaybillServiceImpl.createWayBillFromInvoice]: 
2020-06-04 17:17:16.376 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Changing isolation level of JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@2044564149 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@27db45f] to 2
2020-06-04 17:17:16.450 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
2020-06-04 17:17:16.451 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2020-06-04 17:17:16.451 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         :   setAutoCommit = false
2020-06-04 17:17:16.457 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@caf1ee0]
2020-06-04 17:17:19.532 DEBUG 1208 --- [nio-9002-exec-4] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1021250378<open>)] for JPA transaction
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: @M.Deinum  In case B " LAZY fields not fetch."

Comment: Please post the actual code as what you posted here simply cannot work. So this code isn;t real code but some dumbed down version which doesn't show the problem.